# How to determine in a python program that a key is inside a nested dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary name poorworkmanshipdic which reads as follows:

```
{'Asia': {'china': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'korea': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'japan': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, 'Europe': {'France': 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'England': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'Germany': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}}
```

I want to determine whether the Value corresponding to Asia's Key (which is a nested dictionary), the key of this nested dictionary contains Iran? When I write the following code, the error is reported as follows:

[image]

How should the code be modified to avoid this error?

Comment: You use a variable called `key_second`, but it's not defined anywhere, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Your account is almost 4 years old, so you should know by now [how to post formatted code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/); but as a refresher, you might want to read [ask]. You might also consider trying to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is a NameError, so you should change your key_second first, and check in Asia dictionary as you were saying.

```
Iran = [0,1,0,0,0,0] # example
for key in poorworkmanshipdic['Asia']: # since ur checking for Asia
    if Iran == poorworkmanshipdic['Asia'][key]:
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

Comment: thanks very much !  If iran is not a constant, but a variable, how should I write the code?

Comment: Can you show me an example of what your Iran variable would look like?